# Why would an incorrect memory allocation to a buffer only cause crashes when compiled in Release mode and not in Debug mode?

Tags: c++, vector, visual-studio-2019, heap-corruption

This is my first ever project that I've managed to complete so I'm a bit unsure of how to reference an executable vs a project being worked on and debugged in "debug mode" or whether there's multiple ways to do so etc, etc.

To be more specific, however, I encountered a heap corruption issue that only occurred when Visual Studio 2019 had been set to Release Mode, spit out the "exe" version of my program, and then went through its first debugging session in that form. It turns out (I'm probably wrong, but this is the last thing I changed before the issue completely disappeared) that the following code:

```
std::unique_ptr<std::vector<Stat>> getSelStudStats(HWND listboxcharnames) {
    std::unique_ptr<std::vector<Stat>> selStats = std::make_unique<std::vector<Stat>>();
    int pos = ListBox_GetCurSel(listboxcharnames);
    int len = ListBox_GetTextLen(listboxcharnames, pos);
    const wchar_t* buffer = new const wchar_t[++len];
    ListBox_GetText(listboxcharnames, pos, buffer);

    for (int i = 0; i < getSize(); i++) {
        Character character = getCharacterPtr(i);

        std::wstring name = character.getName();
        if (name.compare(buffer) == 0) {
            *selStats = character.getAllStats();
            return selStats;
        }
    }
    return selStats;
    delete[] buffer;
}
```

was not assigning the correct size to the `buffer` variable through `len`. By adding the prefix increment operator to `len`, the null terminator character that would come along with the list box's text was now being accounted for; Consequently, the heap corruption error stopped occurring.

While I'm glad to have figured out the issue, I don't know why VS2019 didn't bring this issue up in Debug Mode. In attempting to debug the issue, I've learned that optimizations in Release Mode can change the structure and order of code execution.

Is there something in this block of code that would create the error I had, but only in Release Mode/executable form?

EDITED: I removed the asterisks that were originally surrounding `++len` in my attempt to highlight the change that I reference making. Apologies for the confusion it, understandably, caused.

Comment: Why are you using `std::unique_ptr<std::vector<Stat>>` instead of just `std::vector<Stat>`? There is no need to allocate the `vector` dynamically. And why are you using `new wchar_t[]` instead of `std::vector<wchar_t>` or even `std::wstring`? You are calling `delete[]` manually, but you are leaking your allocated `buffer` if its value is found in your `Character` list. You are also not checking the return values of `ListBox_GetCurSel()`, `ListBox_GetTextLen()`, or `ListBox_GetText()` for failures.

Comment: @tadman There is no problem with using `++len` in that context, it is simply increasing the `len` to add room for a null terminator, and that increment is happening before the value is being passed to `new[]`.  This is required by `ListBox_GetText()`.  I'd be more concerned that an array of `const wchar_t` is being allocated, rather than an array of `wchar_t`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Double-de-reference, then increment, then double-dereference *again*? Or is that just indicating "bold"? `len` is an integer here, so that must be a typo of some kind.

Comment: @tadman You can't dereference an integer, or apply `*` without another integer. So I'm assuming the OP is not actually using `**` in their real code, but added that here on SO expecting `++` to be displayed in bold, which it won't inside a code block.

Comment: @RemyLebeau That's my guess, just seeking clarification.

Comment: @viracocha I just realized that you are also leaking your `buffer` even if you don't find its value in your `Character` list, because your `delete[]` statement is after your final `return selStats;` statement.  All the more reason to get rid of `new[]`.  And better, get rid of the `unique_ptr` altogether and just `return character.getAllStats();` when a match is found, and `return vector<Stat>();` when no match is found.

Comment: When your code has a bug that causes undefined behavior at runtime, such as overrunning a buffer, it's very common to have it fail in release mode and not in debug mode (or vice versa).  This discrepancy by itself doesn't mean anything.

Comment: This is not nice `**++**len`. I don't think that is readable. Break this up into multiple lines and make sure it is documented what it does.

Comment: Your `delete[] buffer;` never runs. You leak it in all cases.

Comment: The **++** notation was my failed attempt at activating the bold option in the text editor when making this post; I'm very sorry for that. My intent was to highlight the change I made to correct the heap corruption error I had dealt with. Secondly, I want to thank everyone who left criticism; I'll be looking into every correction immediately.

Comment: I think you did not have space for the terminating null character in your original code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/crt-debug-heap-details?view=vs-2019&redirectedfrom=MSDN) explain the behavior:

> When you request a memory block, the debug heap manager allocates from the base heap a slightly larger block of memory than requested and returns a pointer to your portion of that block. For example, suppose your application contains the call: malloc( 10 ). In a Release build, malloc would call the base heap allocation routine requesting an allocation of 10 bytes. In a Debug build, however, malloc would call _malloc_dbg, which would then call the base heap allocation routine requesting an allocation of 10 bytes plus approximately 36 bytes of additional memory.

So in debug you don't overrun your buffer. However, it may cause other bugs later (but unlikely for one byte overrun.)